# How do I find Appy 1000mg's alternate ending?

Tags: appy-1000mg

I'm playing the enhanced edition of [Appy 1000mg](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-20/?action=preview&uid=2982). The author claims he added an alternate ending to the game but I'm having a great deal of trouble finding it. The only ending I can find is the one where

> Pixelle turns out to be dead and the robot throws himself off a cliff into the sea.

Does this alternate ending actually exist? If so, how do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the alternate ending by

> finding the grave, then going back to pick up a pill. Dying after that put me back near the cliff. Walk to the right.

The new ending isn't much, but at least that's one mystery solved.

Comment: Ahh, okay! I had gone back to pick up a pill but hadn't tried dying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jumping off the edge, do something else.

Comment: So the "alternate ending" is simply not getting the normal ending? Tsk.